# A clustering algorithm that accepts an arbitrary distance function

Tags: algorithm, cluster-analysis

I have about 200 points in Cartesian plane (2D). I want to cluster these points to k clusters with respect to arbitrary distance **function** (not matrix) and get the so-called centroid or representatives of these clusters. I know kmeans does this with respect to some special distance functions such as Euclidean, Manhattan, Cosine, etc. But, kmeans cannot handle arbitrary distance function because for example in centroid-updating phase of kmeans with respect to Euclidean distance function, mean of the points in each cluster is the LSE and minimizes the sum of distances of the nodes in the cluster to its centroid (mean); however, mean of the points may not minimize the ditances when the distance function is something arbitrary. Could you please help me about it and tell me if you know about any clustering algorithms that can work for me?

Comment: First, note that in the literature, "distance" means: (1) `d(x,y)=d(y,x)`, (2) `d(x,y) <= d(x,z) + d(z,y)`, (3) `d(x,y) = 0  if and only if x=y`. Is this correct in your case as well?

Comment: Thanks for your consideration. No, actually 1 and 3 hold in our case, but not 2. There might be x,y, and z for which d(x,y) > d(x,z) + d(z,y).

Answer (score 2):

If you replace "mean" with "most central point in cluster", then you get the [k-medoids](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-medoids) algorithm. Wikipedia claims that a metric is required, but I believe that to be incorrect, since I can't see where the majorization-minimization proof needs the triangle inequality or even symmetry.

Comment: Thanks for your consideration. What I want is something like a centroid in kmeans or representative that is different from the nodes themselves. But, kmedoids gives me one of my nodes as the representative (medoid) of each cluster.

Comment: @user3314148 Without more structure, probably the only answer is to let the candidates for a "centroid" be abstract convex combinations of the points (i.e., a 200-element nonnegative vector summing to 1, where each point is identified with its standard basis vector). Then, define distances between centroid and point (e.g., weighted average distance), a centrality criterion (e.g., maximum weighted average distance to the cluster points), and a way of finding the centroid (e.g., linear programming).

Comment: The first part of your idea is OK; but, the questions are: how can I define distances between **unknown** centroids and points? What should be the weight that any point can get? Actually the structure of my distance function is that the distance between nodeA and nodeB is calculated by considering the barriers one faces in the path, their corresponding costs, and the euclidean distance between the two points.

Comment: @user3314148 If you already have a meaningful notion of intermediate point, then the problem that needs solving is to find a way to improve the centrality of the point representing the cluster given the membership of the cluster.

Comment: Thanks. It makes sense. But, again the problem is what a meaningful notion of intermediate point can be and how to improve the centrality of the **unknown** point representing the cluster. Can you tell me more about it? Or do you know any papers o reports in which I may be able to find something about the things you said?

Answer (score 2):

There are various clustering algorithms that can work with arbitrary distance functions, in particular:

- hierarchical clustering
- k-medoids (PAM)
- DBSCAN
- OPTICS
- many many more - get some good clustering book and/or software

But the only one which enforces `k` clusters *and* uses a "cluster representative" model is k-medoids. You may be putting too many constraints on the cluster model to get a wider choice.

Comment: Thanks for your consideration. What I want is something like a centroid in kmeans or representative that is different from the nodes themselves. But, kmedoids gives me one of my nodes as the representative (medoid) of each cluster.

Comment: Why? Even k-means won't guarantee the cluster representatives to be disjoint from the data points. As long as you keep narrowing down your choices, you'll get less algorithms to use and not more... so reconsider, if you ''really need'' all these restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want something that represents a centroid but is not one of the data points, a technique I once used was to perform something like Kmedoids on N random samples, then I took all the members  of each cluster and used them as samples to build a classifier which returned a class label... in the end each class label returned from the classifier ends up being an abstract notion of a set of cluster/centroids. I did this for a very specific and nuanced reason, I know the flaws.
If you don't want to have to specify K, and your vectors are not enormous and super sparse, then I would take a look at the cobweb clustering in JavaML, JavaML also has a decent KMedoids.